# How do I populate the join table I made for a has_and_belongs_to_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, Event and Vip, each associated with HABTM relationship.
I have a events_vips table with columns for vip_id, and event_id

My new event form:

```
<%= form_for [@organization, @event] do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :when %>
        <%= f.date_select :when %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :vip %>
        <%= f.select :vip_id, options_for_select(@organization.vips.all.map {|v| [v.name, v.id]}) %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

My events controller:

```
    def new
        @organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
        @event = @organization.events.new
    end

    def create
        @organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
        @event = @organization.events.build(event_params)

        if @event.save
            redirect_to organization_path(@organization)
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
```

I want my events_vips table to get populated with a new event/vip relationship when I create an event. Or is that the wrong way to do it?

**Edit:**

My models looks like:

```
class Vip < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :organization
    has_and_belongs_to_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  has_and_belongs_to_many :vips
end
```

Comment: Have you declared your associations in the models?

Comment: Yes, I believe I have. I edited my post to show what my models are

Answer (score 0):

I would use `has_many :events, :through => :some_table_name` and `has_many :organizations, :through => :some_table_name` rather than a habtm. The reason for this is that, with the habtm, you are limited in several ways. First, the join table name is restricted to `events_organizations` because of the alphabetical nature of the habtm construct, and with has_many :through you can use an arbitrary table name that can be more descriptive.

More importantly, you cannot store any other information about the relationship in a habtm join table.  In the has_many :through, for example, you could store the table number, arrival time, dock scheduling, or other information that applies to a specific organization *for a specific event* in the join table, where it belongs.  This way, the join table stores not only the relationship, but information about the nature of that relationship.

In either case, the answer to your question is to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :your_join_table_model` in the model that you will be manipulating the data from (which could be both).

[Here is part 1 of a railscast dedicated to the subject.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

[Here is a link to the HABTM checkboxes railscast, if you wanted to go that route.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes)

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the vip from your params and it to the `event#vips`.

```
def create
    @organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
    @event = @organization.events.build(event_params)

    if @event.save
        vip = Vip.find(event_params[:vip_id])
        @event.vips << vip # this will create the association
        redirect_to organization_path(@organization)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

now its always a good idea to add validation checks, for instance insuring that a vip param came in the form, but the above is how to actually forge the association. once the event is saved, its vip association can be made.